# Is the "difference-integral" of an integrable function integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

assume $f$ is Lebesgue integrable (on $\mathbb{R}$) and $h >0$. Is it true that then the double integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{x}^{x+h} f(u) \, du \, dx$ always exists? Intuitively I have a feeling that the answer is yes but I'm not able to prove it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Since $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_x^{x+h} |f(u)|du dx \le h  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f(u)|du$, the function $(x,u) \mapsto f(u) 1_{]x,x+h]}(x)$ is integrable.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks for your answer, there should be a $u$ in the argument of your indicator, i.e. $(x,u) \mapsto f(u) 1_{]x,x+h]}(u)$, correct? Also, if I understand correctly, you basically just apply Fubini, so your inequality is in fact an equality, right? Apparently I wasn't seeing the woods for the trees... :-)

Comment: Yes, the parameter should be $u$, sorry about that. Yes, it is an inequality, but you only care about integrability, after that Fubini lets you conclude that iterated integral exists.

Comment: Got it, thanks!